# Why did apt-get purge removed nearly my whole ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

Normally I remove packages with `apt-get purge <package>`. But nearly an hour ago, I crashed my whole system by removing a package. I never had the problem ago, so I do not understand what my mistake was.

I tried to set up an LDAP server on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop and had trouble with slapd. It was not reinstallable - a subroutine of dpkg returned error 1. It was recommended to purge the packet libldap-2.4-2

So I did. The result can be seen in /var/log/apt/history.log:

```
Start-Date: 2015-01-11  22:32:22
Commandline: apt-get purge libldap-2.4-2
Purge: libtotem-plparser17:amd64 (3.4.5-1), libreoffice-pdfimport:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), libreoffice-base-core:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), kerneloops-daemon:amd64 (0.12+git20090217-3ubuntu8), ubuntuone-client-gnome:amd64 (4.0.0-0ubuntu1), gconf2:amd64 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2), pulseaudio-module-gconf:amd64 (4.0-0ubuntu11), libgdata13:amd64 (0.14.1-1), librasqal3:amd64 (0.9.32-1), libapache2-mod-fcgid:amd64 (2.3.9-1), apturl:amd64 (0.5.2ubuntu4), python-samba:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), virtualbox:amd64 (4.3.10-dfsg-1), apache2-mpm-prefork:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1), libreoffice-writer:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), apt-transport-https:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.6), gconf-service-backend:amd64 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2), libapache2-mod-proxy-html:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1), libbonoboui2-0:amd64 (2.24.5-0ubuntu3), gnome-terminal:amd64 (3.6.2-0ubuntu1), libapache2-mod-php5:amd64 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5), libubuntuoneui-3.0-1:amd64 (4.0.0-0ubuntu1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (38.0.2125.104-1), unity-scope-gdocs:amd64 (0.9+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1), whoopsie:amd64 (0.2.24.6), libreoffice-impress:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.325), libreoffice-help-de:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu1), deja-dup-backend-gvfs:amd64 (30.0-0ubuntu4), php5-ldap:amd64 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5), libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), compiz-gnome:amd64 (0.9.11.3+14.04.20141104-0ubuntu1), php5-curl:amd64 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5), libquvi7:amd64 (0.4.1-1ubuntu3), unity:amd64 (7.2.3+14.04.20140826-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-draw:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), python3-pycurl:amd64 (7.19.3-0ubuntu3), libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni:amd64 (3.8.2-3), python-ldap:amd64 (2.4.10-1build1), lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure:amd64 (1.1-0ubuntu2), python3-software-properties:amd64 (0.92.37.2), libreoffice-core:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), openswan:amd64 (2.6.38-1), libreoffice-gnome:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), gnome-terminal-data:amd64 (3.6.2-0ubuntu1), phpldapadmin:amd64 (1.2.2-5ubuntu1.1), unity-scope-gdrive:amd64 (0.9+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1), libcmis-0.4-4:amd64 (0.4.1-3ubuntu4), compiz:amd64 (0.9.11.3+14.04.20141104-0ubuntu1), gitg:amd64 (0.2.7-2), libgnome2-common:amd64 (2.32.1-4ubuntu1), unity-lens-photos:amd64 (1.0+14.04.20140318-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-presentation-minimizer:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), libfolks-eds25:amd64 (0.9.5-1ubuntu5), omd-1.20:amd64 (0.trusty), liboauth0:amd64 (1.0.1-1), curl:amd64 (7.35.0-1ubuntu2.2), gconf-service:amd64 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2), system-config-printer-common:amd64 (1.4.3+20140219-0ubuntu2.2), network-manager-gnome:amd64 (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.3), gnome-contacts:amd64 (3.8.3-1ubuntu1), libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8), gconf-editor:amd64 (3.0.1-2ubuntu1), virtualbox-dkms:amd64 (4.3.10-dfsg-1), gnome-media:amd64 (3.4.0-1ubuntu2), thin-client-config-agent:amd64 (0.8), samba-common-bin:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), spotify-client:amd64 (0.9.11.27.g2b1a638.81-1), libldb1:amd64 (1.1.16-1), libgksu2-0:amd64 (2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu4), libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.5.3-1), libgconf2-4:amd64 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2), python-pycurl:amd64 (7.19.3-0ubuntu3), ldap-utils:amd64 (2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8), virtualbox-qt:amd64 (4.3.10-dfsg-1), libreoffice-help-en-us:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu1), gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0:amd64 (4.0.0-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-ogltrans:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), gir1.2-gdata-0.0:amd64 (0.14.1-1), samba-libs:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), libcurl3-nss:amd64 (7.35.0-1ubuntu2.2), python3-uno:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), gvfs-backends:amd64 (1.20.1-1ubuntu1), pidgin-libnotify:amd64 (0.14-9ubuntu2), gstreamer0.10-gconf:amd64 (0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu5), slapd:amd64 (2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8), python-gconf:amd64 (2.28.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2), libgnomevfs2-common:amd64 (2.24.4-1ubuntu6), libgnome2-0:amd64 (2.32.1-4ubuntu1), python-smbc:amd64 (1.0.14.1-0ubuntu2), git:amd64 (1.9.1-1), libgnomeui-0:amd64 (2.24.5-3), gir1.2-gconf-2.0:amd64 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2), libreoffice-gtk:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), smbclient:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 (2.24.4-1ubuntu6), libcurl3:amd64 (7.35.0-1ubuntu2.2), libgnome2-bin:amd64 (2.32.1-4ubuntu1), evolution-data-server:amd64 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.5), libcmis-0.2-2:amd64 (0.2.3-1), software-center:amd64 (13.10-0ubuntu4.1), git-core:amd64 (1.9.1-1), system-config-printer-gnome:amd64 (1.4.3+20140219-0ubuntu2.2), gconf-defaults-service:amd64 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2), transmission-gtk:amd64 (2.82-1.1ubuntu3.1), mythes-de:amd64 (20120516-2), libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0:amd64 (3.0.0-1ubuntu2), libraptor2-0:amd64 (2.0.13-1), ubuntu-tweak:amd64 (0.8.7-1~quantal1), system-config-printer-udev:amd64 (1.4.3+20140219-0ubuntu2.2), apache2:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1), software-properties-common:amd64 (0.92.37.2), python-cupshelpers:amd64 (1.4.3+20140219-0ubuntu2.2), apache2-bin:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1), unity-scope-musicstores:amd64 (6.9.0+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1), mythes-en-us:amd64 (4.2.1-0ubuntu1.1), python-ldb:amd64 (1.1.16-1), librdf0:amd64 (1.0.17-1), software-properties-gtk:amd64 (0.92.37.2), libreoffice-presenter-console:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), librhythmbox-core6:amd64 (2.97-1ubuntu6.1), seahorse:amd64 (3.10.2-0ubuntu1), darktable:amd64 (1.4-2), libflickcurl0:amd64 (1.25-1ubuntu1), libreoffice-math:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), gnome-user-share:amd64 (3.0.4-0ubuntu1), aisleriot:amd64 (3.10.2-1), libsmbclient:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), nautilus-share:amd64 (0.7.3-1ubuntu5), libreoffice-calc:amd64 (4.2.7-0ubuntu2), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.35.0-1ubuntu2.2), pidgin:amd64 (2.10.9-0ubuntu3.2), gksu:amd64 (2.0.2-6ubuntu2)
```

After a while, I interruped it with CTRL-C. But what was the cause of the removal of all those packages? Never had problems with it before.

**Edit**: I found out that I can simulate purges. and `apt-get purge -s libldap-2.4-2` lists all of my installed packages.

Answer (score 3):

All the packages apt-get tried to remove depend on `libldap-2.4-2` - you can check it with `apt-cache showpkg libldap-2.4-2` (look at the section "reverse depends").

Since removing a package would brake those that are depending on it, the behaviour of apt-get is to remove those as well (and if those removals would break other installations, even more packages could be removed).

Comment: Thats interesting. I always thought that apt-get purge would only remove libldap's dependencies in this case. And not also everything what depends on libldap.

I also wonder why nearly all of my packages depend on libldap. I thought I installed it by setting up my LDAP server.